# "Cannot be resolved as a type"

Tags: php, eclipse, static, composer-php

I'm using "Eclipse" and with a simple test code like that one :

```
class Example {    
    public static function isStatic() {
        return "808";
    }
}
class App {
    public static function isTest() {
        return Example::isStatic();
    }
}
```

But I dont know why but Eclipse still telling me that "Example" in "return Example::isStatic();" cannot be resolved as a type. Why ? It's like a gag.

I try to search a solution in the SO's website but i have not find any answer that work.

If you have any hint that could help, you are welcome :)

EDIT : I'm made a little change in my question because in my previous example, you could use self and that worked fine but in the end, that did not really solve my problem. That one is more accurate to my problem

Comment: `self::isStatic()`

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly but self is not a solution in what I'm trying to achieve. I made a little change for showing something closer of my problem.

Comment: Haa thats not a little change :)

Comment: So how do you run `App::isTest()`

Comment: finally is your code works or it's just eclipse ide problem? I've tested it on phpfiddle.org - it works )

Comment: `echo App::isTest();`

Comment: yeah maybe not ^^' For now, I cannot really run it because I have the same problem that with Example::isTest(). Everytime, I use a className with a static function, eclipse tell me that the class cannot be resolved as a type. Anw, I was trying to use it in PHPUnit for making some test

Comment: It's just Eclipse and the way it shows certain things, it doesn't complain if you change it to `return \Example::isStatic();` (just putting the \ shows it's in the global namespace.

Comment: I think it's a problem with eclipse but I've found yet where that come from. I have just tried to add a \ in the global namespace and in the return like you propose Nigel Ren. And Eclipse still telling me '"Cannot be resolved as a type”.

Comment: @Latsuj I guess it's related [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1091599/) ... It's related to bug 496463. PDT doesn't work well if you have everything in one file.

Comment: @Wizard Good thinking but even if I split the two class in two differents files. The error is still poping. But I'm sure it's something close and related with PDT or build path. I still searching.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer, I find the problem by myself.
In fact, I was using Eclipse Photon and this software is still in beta... I download it thinking it was already release.

I try the same manipulation with Eclipse Oxygen and everything working fine :)

Thank all for your answer and have fun developping.